# "Preview" cannot be resolved to a type, imports are defined

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-camera, preview

Why is Eclipse telling me that Preview cannot be resolved to a type??

Where is Preview defined?

Yes, I have tried ctrl+shift+o

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Preview preview;
    MediaRecorder recorder;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be an [SDK Class](https://developer.android.com/index.html#q=Preview). What is `Preview`?

Comment: *Its an Object Type* so's anything else in Java. Be more detailed. Is it from an external library, is it your own class? Have you tried cleaning the project?

Comment: Why are you asking *us* where one of *your* classes is?

Comment: Where is the import for the Preview class? Or else you need to show the code Preview for the Preview class if it is your own.

Answer (score 2):

`Preview` is not imported. Which is why it's giving you the error.

As for why it's not imported it depends.

May be it's a typo and the wrong . If it's a custom class you wrote yourself try clean and build.

Or you may have not added the library containing that class, which is more likely if eclipse doesn't offer a quick-fix by importing the class.